# How can I optimize a code that is using xarray for better performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-xarray

I'm trying to extract climate data from various .nc files I have but the process is taking extremely long, I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to extract the data for every day of June, July, August for the next 79 years. But I'm a novice programmer and I realize there might've been a few oversights by me (efficiency wise) that might've resulted in a slightly better performance.

This is the snippet

```
def calculateTemp(coords, year, model):

    """
    takes in all coordinates of a line between two grid stations and the year

    converts the year into date

    takes average of temperature of each day of the month of June for each 
    coordinate and then takes average of all coordinates to find average temp
    for that line for the month of June
    """
    print(year)

    # coords represents a list of different sets of coordinates between two grids

    temp3 = 0       # sum of all temps of all coordinates
    for i in range(0, len(coords)):
        temp2 = 0
        counter = 0

        # this loop represents that the 15 years data is being extracted for  
        # each coordinate set and average of those 15 years is being taken
        for p in range(0, 15):   

            temp1 = 0       # sum of all temps for one coordinate in all days of June, tuly, august
            if year+ p < 100:
                # this loop represents the months of jun, jul, aug
                for j in range(6, 9):
                    # 30 days of each month
                    for k in range(1, 31):
                        if k < 10:

                            # this if-else makes a string of date
                            date = '20'+str(year+p)+'-0'+str(j)+'-0'+str(k)
                        else:
                            date = '20'+str(year+p)+'-0'+str(j)+'-'+str(k)

                        # there are 3 variants of the climate model
                        # for years upto 2040, between 2041-2070
                        # and between 2071 and 2099
                        # hence this if else block

                        if year+p < 41:   
                            temp1 += model[0]['tasmax'].sel(
                                lon=coords[i][1], lat=coords[i][0], time=date, method='nearest').data[0]
                        elif year+p >= 41 and year+p <71:
                            temp1 += model[1]['tasmax'].sel(
                                lon=coords[i][1], lat=coords[i][0], time=date, method='nearest').data[0]
                        else:
                            temp1 += model[2]['tasmax'].sel(
                                lon=coords[i][1], lat=coords[i][0], time=date, method='nearest').data[0]
                counter += 1
                avg = temp1/(len(range(0,30))*len(range(6,9)))
                temp2 += avg
        temp3 += temp2/counter
    Tamb = temp3/len(coords)

    return Tamb
```

Is there anyway I can increase the performance of this code and optimize it?

Comment: Why are you mentioning nc files? Are they relevant?

Comment: I thought they might be, I might be wrong.

Comment: Please show a minimal example with random data.

Comment: If xarray is anything like numpy you can vectorize this pretty easily

Comment: You can build all the dates first and then make a dict of dates as keys and values as the value your model gives for a particular date. And then just operate on this dict to calculate the averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced the innermost loops `k in range(1,31)`and `j in range(6,9)`into a dict comprehension to generate all the dates and corresponding value from your `model`. Then simply averaged these values for every value of `p` and then for every `coord` in `coords`.

Give this a shot. Dicts should make the processing faster. Also check if the averages are exactly how you are calculating them in your function.

```
def build_date(year,p,j,k):
    return '20'+str(year+p)+'-0'+str(j)+'-0'+str(k) if k<10 else '20'+str(year+p)+'-0'+str(j)+'-'+str(k)



def calculateTemp(coords, year, model):

    func2 = lambda x,date:model[x]['tasmax'].sel(lon=coords[i][1], 
                                                 lat=coords[i][0], 
                                                 time=date, 
                                                 method='nearest').data[0]

    print(year)

    out = {}
    for i in range(len(coords)):
        inner = {}
        for p in range(0,15):

            if year + p < 100:
                dates = {build_date(year,p,j,k):func2(0,build_date(year,p,j,k)) if year+p<41 \
                         else func2(1,build_date(year,p,j,k)) if (year+p >= 41 and year+p <71) \
                         else func2(2,build_date(year,p,j,k))
                         for j in range(6,9) \
                         for k in range(1,31) }

                inner[p] = sum([v for k,v in dates.items()])/len(dates)

        out[i] = inner

    coord_averages = {k : sum(v.values())/len(v) for k,v in out.items() }
    Tamb = sum([v for k,v in coord_averages.items()])/len(coord_averages)
    return Tamb
```

Comment: Thanks man, this looks a whole lot cleaner than the mess I wrote up, I'll look more into dict comprehensions. Sadly, the performance didn't really improve that much, I'm guessing the problem lies with xarray and how it handles search within the datasets. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @HamzaWaheed I was looking at the documentation. Why don't you try to do operations in `xarray`itself. You need basic operations like `sum` and `average` which are available in `xarray`. Or also if you can convert your `xarray`to `dataframe` these operations can be done in `pandas` which might be a bit faster.